# Filtering NSArray string elements

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

So, basically I have an `NSArray`.

I want to get an array with the contents of the initial array after having filtered those e.g. NOT beginning by a given prefix.

It think using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` is the best way; but I'm not sure on how I could do it...

This is my code so far (in a `NSArray` category actually) :

```
- (NSArray*)filteredByPrefix:(NSString *)pref
{
    NSMutableArray* newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

    for (NSString* s in self)
    {
        if ([s hasPrefix:pref]) [newArray addObject:s];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Is it the most Cocoa-friendly approach? What I want is something as fast as possible...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a much simpler way using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [anArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like  %@", [pref stringByAppendingString:@"*"]];
```

This filters the array by checking that it matches the string made up of your prefix followed by a wildcard.

If you want to check the prefix case-insensitively, use `like[c]` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to compare string anywhere in the word: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*",keyword]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use -indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:.  For example:

```
NSIndexSet* indexes = [anArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj hasPrefix:pref];
}];
NSArray* newArray = [anArray objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`  method of `NSArray` class. **Available in Mac OS X v10.6 and later**.

```
@implementation NSArray (hasPrefix)

-(NSMutableArray *)filteredByPrefix:(NSString *)pref
{
    NSMutableArray* newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([ obj hasPrefix:pref]) {
            [newArray addObject:obj];
            return YES;
        } else
            return NO;
    }];

    return [newArray autorelease];

}

@end
```